# How to get the ID of the listitem being clicked on button event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list item with anchor tag and a button, on click of the button i need to get the li selected. how do i do using Jquery. I am not aware as how do I get the clicked event of li . my html code is as :

```
<ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="#" rel="css/default.css" id="default" >
            <div class="r1"></div>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="css/winter.css" id="winter">
            <div class="r2"></div>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="css/spring.css" id="spring">
            <div class="r3"></div>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="css/summer.css" id="summer">
            <div class="r4"></div>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="css/autumn.css" id="autumn">
            <div class="r5"></div>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="sbutton_in" style="margin: 25px auto auto 80px;"  id="btnapply">Apply</a> </div>



$("#btnapply").click(function(){

    //code to get the id of the selected li     
});
```

Comment: How do you selected the `li` element?

Comment: on click i select the li

Comment: *How* exactly? What are you doing to indicate one of the list items was selected? They are not "selectable" by default. Please post the corresponding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply click event for li,

```
$('ul#nav li').on('click',function() {
  $('ul#nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then,

```
$("#btnapply").click(function(){
   var ID = $('ul#nav li.active').attr('id');
});
```

Here in ID you will get ID of selected li.

Edit: You need to give unique ID to each li.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected li as an object in a variable like,

```
  var active=null;

  $('ul#nav li').on('click',function() {
  active=$(this);
  });
```

Then

```
 $("#btnapply").click(function(){
  var ID = active.find('a').attr('id');
 });
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6BV9f/3/)