# Need a way to get an attr from one of many of the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, dom

I'm trying to access the id of an element, and slice off the num to piece together a url for an ajax call. I'm mainly using JQuery.

I have experimented with .attr() and .data() and found that they only return the first match, so everytime it would 1, no matter if I clicked on 1, 4, or 54.

.get() only returns the HTML header object, and I haven't yet found a way to access that and possibly pull out an id num.

The code:

```js
$('.display').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get category from h4's parent div
    let $parent = $('h4').parent();
    let $cat = $parent.attr('class');
    let cat = String($cat);
    //get id to search for...currently only returning id_1, not unique id
    let $id = $('h4').get();  //need correct method here
    console.log($id);
    //slice off num to use in ajax url req
    if($id.length == 4) {
        id_num = $id.slice(-1) + '/';
    } else if ($id.length == 5) {
        id_num = $id.slice(-2) + '/';
    } else {
        id_num = $id.slice(-3) + '/';
    }
    console.log(id_num);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/' + $cat + id_num,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h3 id="title">I made the Kessel Run in 12 parsecs.</h3>
            <form id ="searchParams" method="POST">
            Now, I want to know about the
            <input list="cats" name="cats">
            <datalist id="cats">
                <option id="people" value="people"></option>
                <option id="planets" value="planets"></option>
                <option id="films" value="films"></option>
                <option id="species" value="species"></option>
                <option id="vehicles" value="vehicles"></option>
                <option id="starships" value="starships"></option>
            </datalist>
            in Star Wars.
           <input id="getInfo" type="submit">
          </form>
          <div class="display"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/twelveparsecs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What element are you trying to get the id from?

Comment: Will `$("input[list='cats']").val()` do? (instead of the current `.get()`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110737/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-listitem-being-clicked-on-button-event 

sorry for the similar question, albeit poorly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript can't be right to the html snippet, it starts with failures on line 2

```
let $parent = $('h4').parent();  
// never matches on your code, you have no h4 tag
let $cat = $parent.attr('class'); 
// attr is no function of undefined, null pointer exception
```

the way to a id can be this this;

```
<div id="test">

<script>
  console.log($('div').attr('id'));
</script>
```

if a tag is given more than 1 time you will get back a array of JQuery object matching on the nodes with the $('div') selector:

```
<div id="1">a</div>
<div id="2">b</div>

<script>
  let listOfElements = $('div');
  for(var i = 0; i < listOfElements.length; i++) {
    var singleElementInList = $(listOfElements[i]);
    var id = singleElementInList.attr('id');
    console.log(id);
  }
</script>
```

the get command is a ajax call to read a response of a url fast

Comment: Sorry, the <h4> is appended to .display by another event function which wasn't in the snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110737/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-listitem-being-clicked-on-button-event   this is also a good way of getting the id of many elements.